# mailto Intent doesn't show recipient address (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

Im trying to send an email from my Android app. With the click of a button, gmail should open and show a new email with my previously defined recipient, subject and email body.

This was how it was working for 2 days but today, the recipient address is not getting copied to the gmail address bar -- only subject and body are getting copied.

this is my code (i havent changed it -- its the same as it was 2 days back):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipient);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: None of those extras are documented for `ACTION_SENDTO`. Put your email address in the string that you are passing to `Uri.parse()`, [the way that `mailto` links have worked on the Web for a couple of decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

Comment: Thank you. the address bar gets copied now... but the subject and body is missing now!

Comment: edited my comment - subject and body doesnt get copied now

Comment: Those two also should go into the `mailto:` link, [the way that mailto links have worked on the Web for a couple of decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

Comment: oh okay i got it now... thanks a lot! weird that the app was working perfectly until today

Answer (score 0):

Add recipient address in String Array,:

Try this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  new String[]{recipient});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```